# Trying to highlight only part of a page

Tags: javascript, html, flask, highlight

I have a working highlighter function. However, it highlights the entire webpage. So if I search for "psalm" for instance, all those get highlighted in the "book_name" part. I want to highlight only the "text" part. I tried, instead of document.body, "document.getElementById" and gave the text an id, but unsurprisingly it only highlighted the first search result. I tried "document.getElementByClass", Name, and Tag as well, but nothing happened when I clicked the button.

```
<table action="/Bible" method="get" class="table table-hover">

    <button onclick="inc(id)" style="background: crimson; display:{{ display_highlight }}">Highlight</button>
    <tbody>
        <h1>Bible</h1>
        <tr>
            <th>Number</th>
            <th>Book</th>
            <th>Chapter</th>
            <th>Verse</th>
            <th>Text</th>
        </tr>
        {% for i in lst %}
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>{{i.number}}</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p><b>{{i.book_name}}</b></p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>{{i.chapter}}</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>{{i.verse}}</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>{{i.text}}</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>

<script>
    var search_upper = {{search_upper|tojson}};
    var search_lower = {{search_lower|tojson}};
    // Works great for passing Flask value to Javascript

    function highlight() {
        document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace (new RegExp (search_upper, 'g'), "<mark>{{search_upper}}</mark>");
        document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace (new RegExp (search_lower, 'g'), "<mark>{{search_lower}}</mark>");
    }

    function dehighlight() {
        document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace (new RegExp (search_upper, 'g'), "<p>{{search_upper}}</p>");
        document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace (new RegExp (search_lower, 'g'), "<p>{{search_lower}}</p>");

        const matches = document.querySelectorAll("mark");
        matches.forEach(mark => {
        mark.remove();
        });
        // Removes all <mark> tags
    }

    var count = 0;

    function inc(){
    count ++;
    if (count % 2 == 0) {
        dehighlight();
    } else {
        highlight();
    }
};
</script>
```